# Conditionally display one of two fields in Display Suite?

Tags: 7, entities

I'm wondering if there is a clever or preferred way of using Display Suite to display one of two fields.

So my case calls for either an image, if it is uploaded, or a EVA (entity views attachment). I have them both displaying correctly, and of course if the image is not uploaded (unpopulated), then the EVA field displays fine. But if the image is uploaded, I want to hide the EVA field.

I guess I could do a custom code field, but I would like to avoid that if there is a built-in method of choosing one over another field. Maybe something with field groups?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only option is a custom code field. 
There have been attempts to make conditional fields possible through the UI, but it was too complex.

Comment: That would probably be a fine solution, but I wouldn't call it the only option. I'm sure you can also hide the EVA from a preprocess function, or even configure the EVA view so it doesn't return anything if an image is present.

Answer (score 4):

Use the field formatter conditions module: https://www.drupal.org/project/ffc

This will give you the same options that you have on a blocks (and more). So you can show the field based on any url pattern just as you would blocks:

http://cl.ly/image/2A2Y373Y3e1J

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Renderkit](https://www.drupal.org/project/renderkit) with [Entity Display Plugin for Field UI](https://www.drupal.org/project/entdispfieldui) for problems like this.

I have not tried it with EVA specifically, but it can embed views displays, among other things.

The integration of the drilldown form into the field UI form is currently a bit clunky, but it works.

I recommend to also enable [Cfr Preset](https://drupal.org/project/cfrpreset).

Preparation:

- Enable entdispfieldui
- Optionally enable cfrpreset

On the "Manage display" page:

- Scroll to the bottom, add an EntDisP field.
- Move the field up into an active Region.
- Click "Save" at the bottom of the page.
- Edit the configuration for the EntDisP field (click the cog-wheel).
- Choose "Chain of responsibility", then "Field with formatter" or "Image with processor".
- Click "Update" on the sub-form.
- Click the cog-wheel again to open the form again.
- Choose "Views display.." for "New item". Choose the views display id.
- Click "Update" on the sub-form.
- Click "Save" at the bottom of the page.

It should work now, but having this configuration within the display configuration is messy.

To avoid this, you can use `cfrpreset`.

On the "Manage display" page:

- Click the cog-wheel again.
- Mouse-hover next to the drilldown select element for "Entity display".
- Click "Create a preset" (opens in new tab).

On the "Add preset" page:

- Choose a name for the preset.
- Save.

On the "Manage display" page:

- Close the sub-form, if it is still open.
- Click the cog-wheel again.
- Choose the preset you just created.
- Click "Update" on the sub-form.
- Click "Save" at the bottom of the page.

Optionally, you can export partial configuration as new presets.

### Screenshots

*I hope these are not too much. Would be great to have an expand/collapse thingie.*

Add EntDisP field.

[image: Add an EntDisP field.]

Configuration with "Field with formatter".

[image: Configure the EntDisP field.]

Alternative configuration with "Image with processor".

[image: Alternative configuration using "Image with processor".]

Export as preset.

[image: Optionally, export as a preset.]

Save the preset.

[image: Save the preset.]

Use the preset instead of the in-place configuration.

[image: Use the preset instead of in-place configuration.]